# Prevent gem pushes to RubyGems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

NPM has the ability to prevent a gem from being published. Is there a way to do the same thing and prevent a gem from being accidentally published to rubygems?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[RubyGems 2.2.0](http://blog.rubygems.org/2013/12/26/2.2.0-released.html) was only recently released, which adds support for this. You need to set `allowed_push_host` to your own gem server. The [documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/publishing/) describes it thus:

> If you want to control who can install a gem, or directly track the activity surrounding a gem, then you’ll want to set up a private gem server. You can set up your own gem server or use a commercial service such as Gemfury.
>
> RubyGems 2.2.0 and newer support the `allowed_push_host` metadata value to restrict gem pushes to a single host. If you are publishing private gems you should set this value to prevent accidental pushes to rubygems.org:

```
Gem::Specification.new 'my_gem', '1.0' do |s|
  # ...
  s.metadata['allowed_push_host'] = 'https://gems.my-company.example'
end
```

**To upgrade RubyGems, just run the following command:**

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: And if you are not publishing private gems to a server but still want to restrict pushes to RubyGems?

Comment: This does not answer the question. Can we set this value to nil so that it won't deploy to rubygems?